# Hadoop YARN vs Yarn package manager command conflict

Tags: javascript, hadoop, yarnpkg

I'm having an issue with the **yarn** command on my machine. I have both **hadoop** and **yarn package manager**(Javascript) installed on my machine. When I run **yarn init** it calls **hadoop's YARN** and responds with :

> Error: Could not find or load main class *path/to/folder*

Can anyone please tell me how to separate the two commands. I am using a 64-bit windows 10 machine.

Comment: At the moment I have to run **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn" init** to initialize a yarn project

Comment: I am in opposite situation trying to run Hadoop yarn and it is asking for package.json seems like trying to run  node package. Any idea how to resolve this.

Comment: You may change the order in path... move hadoop path before yarn, then use yarnpkg

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Turns out you can just use

```
yarnpkg
```

instead of

```
yarn
```