# Alias yarn to yarnpkg to avoid conflict with Hadoop Yarn

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, yarnpkg

I have Yarn (package manager) already installed on my machine, but I now have to install Apache Hadoop. When I tried doing that with `brew install hadoop`, I got the error -

```
Error: Cannot install hadoop because conflicting formulae are installed.
  yarn: because both install `yarn` binaries

Please `brew unlink yarn` before continuing.

Unlinking removes a formula's symlinks from /usr/local. You can
link the formula again after the install finishes. You can --force this
install, but the build may fail or cause obscure side-effects in the
resulting software.
```

This seems to be because Hadoop's Yarn conflicts with yarn from yarnpkg.

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/673), they have no intention of renaming yarnpkg's yarn, but they have [added `yarnpkg` as an alias to `yarn`](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/commit/cefa9a368dd3df1a1f1ecd9e50de9c5fabefbc92).

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739402/hadoop-yarn-vs-yarn-package-manager-command-conflict) just mentions using `yarnpkg` instead of `yarn` to avoid the conflict, but there's no steps on how to do so.

I'd appreciate any help on how to setup `yarnpkg` alias so that I can install Hadoop alongside yarn.

Comment: Just wondering if you've found instructions on setting up yarnpkg alias?

Comment: @user8888 You have to add the yarn `/bin` folder to you `PATH` environment variable

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it with unlinking and linking yarn again.

```sh
brew unlink yarn && brew link yarn
```

You can add an alias in `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` as follows

```sh
alias yarn='command yarnpkg'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that `brew link yarn` as mentioned in the answer above won't work.

I speculated whether that might link only the non-conflicting `yarnpkg`, but turns out it refused to link either, which seems quite fair.

Conceptually, (with yarn package manager unlinked) what you can do is add an alias to your .bash_profile like `alias yarnpkg /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.0/bin/yarnpkg`

Note that won't be robust to when you brew upgrade yarn to a new version.

Also, adding that directory to your path is not a good idea, because that makes ambiguous the fact you have two separate programs called `yarn` installed.

An alternative to adding the bash alias is to just add the *single, non-conflicting* symlink manually in the same way brew link would do if it didn't refuse, as mentioned above:

`ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.0/bin/yarnpkg /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg`

It remains to be seen what happens when yarnpkg is updated, so keep an eye out for that. Since yarnpkg is not, apparently, symlinked  by brew (except we sneakily added one), if brew doesn't update that symlink to point to the new version, then yarnpkg will stop working when you `brew upgrade yarn`, unless you repeat the manual `ln` as above pointing to the new version.

## Update

Just tried it. Brew actually refuses to upgrade yarn, giving the reason that it conflicts with hadoop.  So, we can `brew unlink hadoop`, as it suggests, then `brew upgrade yarn`.

Then, `brew unlink yarn`, `brew link hadoop` (hadoop has far more needed links than yarnpkg), then, finally, recreate the yarnpkg symlink with new version like so: `/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.1/bin/yarnpkg`

Quite long winded, but works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier way to solve this issue:

- install `hadoop` using `HomeBrew`
- manually install `yarn` using `tarball`

Step by step guide if already installed conflicting `yarn` and `hadoop` using `Homebrew`:

##### Clean up conflict in `Homebrew` and Install `Hadoop`

1. `brew uninstall yarn`
2. `brew uninstall hadoop`
3. `brew install hadoop`
4. `brew link hadoop`(optional if `hadoop` is already installed by `HomeBrew` but not linked)

##### Instal `yarn` using `tarball`

1. `brew install wget` (if does not have wget)
2. `cd /opt`
3. `wget https://yarnpkg.com/latest.tar.gz` (use `sudo` if permission denied)
4. `tar zvxf latest.tar.gz` (use `sudo` if permission denied)
5. open any of the following files `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc` in the code editor to add `yarn` to the path
6. Add these two lines 
   `export PATH="$PATH:/opt/yarn-[version]/bin"` 
   `` export PATH="$PATH:`yarn global bin`" ``
7. see more on the [yarn official doc](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#mac-stable)

Answer (score 0):

I have

```bash
hyarn () {
        alias yarn=/opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
}

jyarn () {
        alias yarn=/usr/local/bin/yarn
}

jyarn
export PATH="$(yarn global bin):$PATH"
hyarn
```

I have this in my dot file to context switch between the two yarn commands. And I am exporting the functions `hyarn` and `jyarn` as

```bash
export hyarn
export jyarn
```

Stays very handy for me.

For example, for Hadoop `yarn`

```bash
fahad in ~ λ hyarn
fahad in ~ λ yarn
Usage: yarn [OPTIONS] SUBCOMMAND [SUBCOMMAND OPTIONS]
 or    yarn [OPTIONS] CLASSNAME [CLASSNAME OPTIONS]
  where CLASSNAME is a user-provided Java class

  OPTIONS is none or any of:
```

and for `yarn` for JS

```bash
fahad in ~ λ jyarn
fahad in ~ λ yarn
yarn install v1.22.10
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
✨  Done in 0.05s.
```